# Android: Is this not how drawing a canvas works?

Tags: android, canvas, drag-and-drop, scale, multi-touch

Am I misunderstanding how translating and scaling a canvas should work? I created a custom view that I can drag and zoom, but it's inside the bounds I set. I thought translating the canvas would redraw the bounds? I want to be able to drag and zoom the image on the whole screen, not in a viewport! I assumed translating the canvas would adjust the viewport.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mIcon.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

This is how I created the view. So basically it is stuck in this 250 x 250 box. I need the view to actually drag around.. I get the feeling I'm doing something stupid but I can't produce the behavior I'm looking for.

```
    MultiTouchImageView view = new MultiTouchImageView(this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250));
```

Comment: I've got a similar problem - I'm not using `canvas.scale()` and `mIcon.draw(canvas)`, but rather `canvas.drawRect()`. The rectangle I draw on the screen moves around, but only within the bounds of the view. It's like the contents of the view are moving but the view itself isn't moving within the layout.

Comment: Try to set left and top margin of the view  in ACTION_MOVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set margins to move view in layout. I've created [test project](https://github.com/Drnkn/DragViewTest) to show the idea, it looks like that:

```
public class DragView extends View {

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private float mDeltaX;
    private float mDeltaY;

    public DragView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DragView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();

                mLastTouchX = event.getRawX();
                mLastTouchY = event.getRawY();

                switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                    mDeltaX = mLastTouchX - lParams.leftMargin;
                    mDeltaY = mLastTouchY - lParams.topMargin;

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    mLastTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    mLastTouchY = event.getRawY();

                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                    params.leftMargin = (int) (mLastTouchX - mDeltaX);
                    params.topMargin = (int) (mLastTouchY - mDeltaY);
                    setLayoutParams(params);

                    break;
                }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: So you're saying that instead of calling `invalidate()` and redrawing the view, the appropriate approach is to not 'redraw' the view but to simply move its margins within its layout?

Comment: Yes, as I know it's the most convenient way to drag view on pre-honeycomb versions.

Comment: In a lot of the tutorials, the code that @pasta12 described is suggested. I'm assuming that code, then, is to move the contents (i.e. canvas) within a view (for example, the bounds are set to `fill_parent`, so the canvas can be drawn anywhere within the bounds of the view).

Comment: I believe @pasta12 code just redraw content in other place, but actual position stays the same. It means it's impossible to click on that view.

Comment: Thanks Vang, this explains the difference in concepts to me. Not sure if @pasta12 will accept it as answer, though.

Comment: Sorry, I should have accepted this a long time ago. I don't know that it directly answers my question, but it is the correct approach to moving things if you are supporting pre-honeycomb, and the approach I found independently.